# How to create a horizontal looping ticker in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a ticker that loops text within the body of a div. I can get it to move the text at a specified rate but I am having trouble figuring out how to get JQuery to loop the text. Once the contents in the div have reached the end, how do I loop it back while still showing rest of the contents from the tail?

Code:

```
var left = -500;
$(document).ready(function(e){
function tick() {
        left++;
        $(".ticker-text").css("margin-left", -left + "px");
        setTimeout(tick, 16);
  }

  tick();
});
```

html:

```
<div class = "ticker-container">
    <div class = "ticker-text">
        start text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
        text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text end     
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mxu4v/1/

Comment: You need to wrap each text section in an element and then move the elements back to the beginning once they are completely out of view.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't wheels out there already that suit your purpose? If you do feel the need to reinvent one, http://workshop.rs/2011/09/news-ticker-in-4-lines-of-jquery/ has a great tutorial on doing vertical tickers. You can make it horizontal by changing the effects (eg. slideLeft instead of slideUp) and the targeted elements (a quick and dodgy solution would be to split your string on "" and then wrap each character with `<span class="tickerChar"></span>`). that said, why not http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just reset the margin when it gets too far left:

```
var width = $('.ticker-text').width(),
    containerwidth = $('.ticker-container').width(),
    left = containerwidth;
$(document).ready(function(e){
    function tick() {
        if(--left < -width){
            left = containerwidth;
        }
        $(".ticker-text").css("margin-left", left + "px");
        setTimeout(tick, 16);
    }
    tick();
});
```

Note that the CSS must be changed so that `.ticker-text` assumes the width of its contents, and not `1000%` as you specified:

```
.ticker-text {
    height: 150%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/fHd4Z/

Answer (score 1):

Just to flesh my comment out into an answer:

As above, I believe you'd be best of using one of the pre existing frameworks designed for this. In terms of a quick knock up of the feature, you could start with something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/B9ruA/

JS:

```
var tickerId="#tickerText";
function tickify(e) {
    var text=$(e).text().split("");
    var newText="";
    for (var i=0;i<text.length;i++) {
        newText+="<span class='tickerChar'>" + text[i] + "</span>";
    }
    $(e).html(newText);
}
tickify(tickerId);
function tick(){
    $(tickerId + " span.tickerChar:first").hide("slide",{direction:"left"},50,function(){$(this).appendTo($(tickerId)).show("slide",{direction:"right"},50);});
}
setInterval(function(){tick()},200);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tickerText">  woo, here is some text for ticking, text that ticks, ticky text to test with  </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.ui-effects-wrapper {
    display:inline;
}
```

notes:

I had to add some css to stop the animated characters being displayed as block (and thus on their own line). You would probably make the selector more specific to not screw with other animations on the page (if you have any).

Obviously this could do with some timing readjustments for smoothness sake - I couldn't be bothered doing the niggly trial and error work behind that but have fun (another reason to use a framework).

in my comment I mentioned the methods slideLeft and slideRight - they don't exist. my bad.